# IF/AND functions from multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, if-this-then-that, google-sheets-cell-format

Would anyone know how to fix this problem? I want cell A676 to categorize based on info from 2 cells C676 and D676.

Basically IF the word "Paypal" is in cell D, AND there is a specific amount in cel C, I want it to categorize it in A676.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Example image]

Comment: Problem starts with multiple '=' signs, you should put just one at the beginning of the formula.
Also brackets are messed up. Your formula should look like =IFERROR(IFS(AND(SEARCH("Paypal",D676)>0,C676=14),"Groceries",
AND(SEARCH("Paypal",D676)>0,C676=45),"Internet",
AND(SEARCH("Paypal",D676)>0,C676=21),"Telephone"),"-")

Answer (score 1):

You need to use IFS() with AND.

See the reference here:

https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-correctly-use-and-or-functions-with-ifs-in-google-sheets/

> Hi This is my code currently i.ibb.co/HTz1L0T/qsdf.png – Lloyd 14 mins
> ago

As outlined by OlegS you are still using multiple = signs in your code with the wrong syntax.

His comment that you should amend it to the following seems right in my view.

```
=IFERROR(IFS(AND(SEARCH("Paypal",D676)>0,C676=14),"Groceries", AND(SEARCH("Paypal",D676)>0,C676=45),"Internet", AND(SEARCH("Paypal",D676)>0,C676=21),"Telephone"),"-")
```

Comment: Hi, I still get the same problem. Can you please help out? What am I doing wrong? :(
Would be great if someone could type out exactly what I need to write down

Comment: What did you try? I use this formula in one of my sheets and it works well... =IF(AND(C4="";D4="");W4;(C4+D4+G4+H4+K4+L4)). The critical thing is the placement of AND with the IF or IFS() as appropriate...

Comment: @Lloyd again you have wrong syntax.
=IFERROR(IFS(AND(SEARCH("Paypal",D676)>0,C676=14),"Groceries"),"-")
Use formula in the answer.

Comment: Thank you and really sorry guys,

The formula works! But how do I add it to my existing formula...? :((  

https://i.ibb.co/9vkwHCJ/qsdfzz.png

Comment: Please explain what you mean by add it to your existing formula? If the answer correctly addresses your issue issue please consider marking it as accepted which will assist others looking for a solution to the same or similar problem. Thank you.